# How many resquest.security() function can be used in total in tradingview account?

Tags: pine-script

i know there is a 400 limit for total alerts  and i know there is a 40 limit for  resquest.security() function in each indicator. Does that mean there is also a 400 limit for total  resquest.security() that can be used ?  i mean for example can i use like 30 indcators that have 40 resquest.security() fuctions each and set alerts for all of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, however, it will slow down your chart. Also, the number of indicators you can have on your chart depends on your subscription type.

[image]